# Use strong algorithm in ScramSha1Authenticator - as per Veracode?

Tags: java, mongodb, sha, veracode

We are using Mongo DB java driver 3.4.1 jar. When we did Veracode testing we found that:

> ScramSha1Authenticator.java line no 215 is using broken or risky cryptographic algorithm

Is there any know resolution/workaround for this?

Since it is a critical issue, we have to address it before moving to production.

Comment: Does Veracode recommend something? Maybe change it to sha256

Comment: Yes. But, How do we change it. It is third party code. not ours. We may have to raise a request to  mongo DB to change it accordingly.

Comment: Yes, probably you'll have to do that. Or you get the code and change it yourself (it's in github if I'm not wrong). Or check with Veracode if you can mitigate this (explain it's a third party code and so on) - not sure how this can be handled with them.

Comment: There's a difference between SCRAM-SHA-1 and SHA-1. Please see also duplicate post answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/WCUgQfN-cn0

Answer (score 1):

This can't be easily changed, because it is not just the driver: [SCRAM-SHA-1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-scram-sha-1/) is the current username-password authentication protocol in the latest version of MongoDB, and it uses SHA-1; the driver can't just unilaterally decide to use SHA-256 instead.

I don't know how committed you are to passing the Veracode tests, but I can see two possible options which let you carry on using MongoDB securely despite the Veracode security report:

1. Get assurance from MongoDB that the SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism is not vulnerable to the well-known [security problems with the SHA-1 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)
2. Instead of using this authentication mechanism, instead use a different mechanism; perhaps [x.509 Certificate Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-x.509/), or [Kerberos Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/kerberos/)